# JavaFX TextField detect when user inputs something

Tags: java, javafx

I want to detect when the user inputs anything into a TextField. I have this:

```
tfContractNumberValue.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println("textfield changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
});
```

The problem with this is that it also detects when I change the text programmatically. I want something that only detects user input and ignores changes made by the code.

Comment: I just wonder why you want to do this: it usually indicates you have two different text values you’re interested in (eg a “committed” and “uncommitted” value). The best solution is often to model both values in your data model, or to let the data model one value and the text field contain the other.

Comment: I use `tfContractNumberValue.setText(...)` in the code and it's triggering the listener, which is what I don't want.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a boolean value to keep track of where something was set from.

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
BooleanProperty setByMyCode = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (setByMyCode.get()) {
        // action to take only when my code has set the value.
    } else {
        // action to take otherwise.
    }

    setByMyCode.set(false);
});
```

Which is used like this:

```
public void setText(String newText) {
    if (!Objects.equals(newText, textField.getText())) {
        setByMyCode.set(true);
        textField.setText(
                newText
        );
    }
}
```

Here is an example you can try:

[image: set by code from empty]
[image: set by code from value]
[image: set by user]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class CodeSetterApp extends Application {
    private static final Random random = new Random(42);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        BooleanProperty setByMyCode = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        Button changeText = new Button("Set to new value");
        changeText.setOnAction(e -> {
            String newText = Integer.toString(
                    random.nextInt(5) + 1
            );

            if (!newText.equals(textField.getText())) {
                setByMyCode.set(true);
                textField.setText(
                        newText
                );
            }
        });

        Label status = new Label();

        textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            status.setText(
                    """
                    From %s to %s.
                    Set by %s
                    """.formatted(
                            getStringValueOrEmpty(oldValue),
                            getStringValueOrEmpty(newValue),
                            setByMyCode.get()
                                    ? "my code."
                                    : "the user or other code."
                    )
            );

            setByMyCode.set(false);
        });

        VBox layout = new VBox(
                10,
                textField,
                changeText,
                status
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setPrefWidth(200);

        changeText.fire();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    private static String getStringValueOrEmpty(String oldValue) {
        return oldValue == null || oldValue.isEmpty() || oldValue.isBlank()
                ? "<empty>"
                : oldValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Notes*

You may wish to take a different approach, as advised by James_D in comments:

> I just wonder why you want to do this: it usually indicates you have two different text values you’re interested in (eg a “committed” and “uncommitted” value). The best solution is often to model both values in your data model, or to let the data model one value and the text field contain the other.

Consider using an action handler rather than a text listener. `TextField` has an [`onAction`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#onActionProperty) property:

> The action handler is normally called when the user types the ENTER key.

So adding an action handler via `textField.setOnAction`, will let you know when the user has completed input and hit ENTER in the text field.

It is possible that some other code could fire the action handler programmatically, but that would be unusual.  If you wanted to know that you could use a similar boolean flag approach provided for the text listener in this example.

Comment: Yes unfortunately this is the only solution

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that my proposal is the only solution.  For instance, you may be able to use [event stream composition with a filter](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) (I think, I didn't try it).  Using a boolean flag in the way I demonstrate here is (I think) a bit simpler for most people to understand (at least for me to understand anyway).  Though, if you are familiar with functional reactive programming, some could argue otherwise, and I could understand that.

Comment: I guess, even with a stream event filter, you have to filter on some property related to the event, which might just end up similar to my proposed solution here where a boolean value is set and it is that boolean value that is used to filter the event stream.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Event Filter:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, (KeyEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println(textField.getText());
        });

        PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
        delay.setOnFinished(event -> textField.setText("Set by code"));
        delay.play();

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(25));
        hBox.getChildren().add(textField);
        hBox.setPrefWidth(300);
        hBox.setPrefHeight(300);

        var scene = new Scene(hBox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Above will set text in textField to "Set by code" after 5 seconds but it will not fire the Event Filter. Every key release in the textField will fire the Event Filter.

Another option is to use setOnKeyReleased:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TextField textField = new TextField();

        PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
        delay.setOnFinished(event -> textField.setText("Set by code"));
        delay.play();

        textField.setOnKeyReleased(keyEvent -> {

            System.out.println(textField.getText());

        });

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(25));
        hBox.getChildren().add(textField);
        hBox.setPrefWidth(300);
        hBox.setPrefHeight(300);

        var scene = new Scene(hBox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Comment: This won’t detect the user entering text by copy and paste with the mouse

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing this out. Maybe the poster can use it anyway. I'm not sure I fully understand what the poster want to achieve.

Comment: @James_D what if you add MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED event filter?

Comment: @Anon give it a try, play around with it.

Comment: @droid but then what if the user has some type of input that's neither a keyboard nor mouse?

Comment: @Anon describe your case with more detail, maybe show more code, then it may be more easy to help you. You can update your post.

Comment: @droid to do the same thing that `textProperty().addListener` does but only for when the user themselves inputs the text